# Why does the year format incorrectly with leading zeros in Oracle SQL date formatting?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01858

Relatively new to SQL. I'm trying to combine several date columns - one for the full date (OPR_DATE), one for the hour of the date (HOUR_ENDING), and one for the minute of that date (OPR_5MIN), and create a new column with the full correct date/hour/minute (VALID_DATE).

I'm able to correctly add the month, day, hour, and minute, but the year reads a 0 for the thousands digit instead of a 2. Ex: 2022 in OPR_DATE is formatted to 0022 in VALID_DATE.

As an example, for the following code, where OPR_DATE is 2/24/2022 12:00:00 AM, HOUR_ENDING is 1.00000, and OPR_5MIN is 5.0000, VALID_DATE is formatted as 2/24/0022 01:05:00 AM.

OPR_DATE is a Datetime, and HOUR_ENDING and OPR_5MIN are Fixed Precision Numbers.

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(r.OPR_DATE, 'fmmm/fmdd/yyyy HH:MI:SS PM') + r.HOUR_ENDING/24 + r.OPR_5min/(24*60), 'fmmm/fmdd/yyyy HH:MI:SS PM') AS VALID_DATE,  
r.OPR_DATE, r.HOUR_ENDING, r.OPR_5MIN, r.DATA_ITEM, r.RESOURCE_NAME, r.VALUE AS REAL_TIME_VALUE, d.VALUE as DAY_AHEAD_VALUE 
FROM ZE_VIEW.MRTU_SLD_FCST_RTM_V  r
JOIN ZE_VIEW.MRTU_SLD_FCST_DAM_V d
ON d.OPR_DATE = r.OPR_DATE AND d.HOUR_ENDING = r.HOUR_ENDING
```

Additionally, note that in the code above, I need to cast VALID_DATE as fmmm/fmdd/yyyy to make the code work, while OPR_DATE is in fmdd/fmmm/yyyy format. If I cast VALID_DATE to the date format like OPR_DATE is in natively (fmmm/fmdd/yyyy), I get the following error:

"Oracle database error 1858: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Error Code: 3834A5EA"

Comment: Your code, with sample data you posted, returns year 2022 in my 21XE database. Could you copy/paste code that runs in your database, with sample data you mentioned, so that we'd see what happened? As of ORA-01858: are you sure that all values stored as strings represent valid DATE datatype values in OPR_DATE column?

Comment: It sounds like OPR_DATE is already a date, not a string; and your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT is something like `MM/DD/YY`. Then your `to_date()` would implicitly convert the year to 22 (as YY), then explicitly back to 0022 (as YYYY). Please edit your question to include the column data types to clarify, and don't apply `to_date()` to something that's already a date.

Comment: Thank you. I added the column types to the question above. OPR_DATE is a Datetime, and HOUR_ENDING and OPR_5MIN are Fixed Precision Numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ZE_VIEW.MRTU_SLD_FCST_RTM_V.OPR_DATE` column appears to be a `DATE` data type.

**NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on a `DATE` as `TO_DATE` expects a string as the first argument and so Oracle will implicitly convert the `DATE` to a string and then pass it to the function to convert back to a `DATE`; at best, this is pointless and, at worst, Oracle will use a different format in the implicit string conversion and your date will be mangled (which is what is happening for you as the date is being implicitly converted to a string with a two-digit year and then converted back expecting a four-digit year).

```sql
SELECT to_char(
         r.OPR_DATE + r.HOUR_ENDING/24 + r.OPR_5min/(24*60),
         'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS PM'
       ) AS VALID_DATE,  
       r.OPR_DATE,
       r.HOUR_ENDING,
       r.OPR_5MIN,
       r.DATA_ITEM,
       r.RESOURCE_NAME,
       r.VALUE AS REAL_TIME_VALUE,
       d.VALUE as DAY_AHEAD_VALUE 
FROM   ZE_VIEW.MRTU_SLD_FCST_RTM_V  r
       JOIN ZE_VIEW.MRTU_SLD_FCST_DAM_V d
       ON     d.OPR_DATE = r.OPR_DATE
          AND d.HOUR_ENDING = r.HOUR_ENDING
```

Comment: Thank you! This gets me partially there; I now have the correct string for `VALID_DATE`. 

I am trying to have `VALID_DATE` be a `DATE` type for plotting in Tableau, and when I try to cast it as a `DATE` type in Tableau, I get the following error:

```Oracle database error 1830: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Error Code: 3834A5EA```

I am able to avoid this error by using the `TO_DATE` function, but as you mention, my date is being mangled with this process.

Comment: @charliep127 If you want a `DATE` then don't use `TO_CHAR` to convert the date you had to a string. Just leave it as a `DATE` and use `r.OPR_DATE + r.HOUR_ENDING/24 + r.OPR_5min/(24*60) AS valid_Date`

Comment: Ahh that makes sense and works! Thank you very much.